What is this 6-pin SMD IC marked IV7NM?
What is this 6-pin SMD IC marked IV7NM? I think is a voltage regulator or a MOSFET. It was in a Jdiag 200.


If you want to attract someone's attention then [edit] your question title to include "SMD, 6-pin, IV7NM". Explain what "Jdiag 200" is and give a wider angle photo to give context. Welcome to EE.SE.

also, avoid doing camera photos of computer screens, if at all possible. Most devices with a screen have some sort of "screenshot to USB drive" function, though that might not be the case for PCB magnifiers. In your case, you draw a red circle around something, definitely on a device with a screenshot function, then you took a part of that. Why? Give us the full context, please.

It is a MP2451DT Step down converter from MPS.
"V7" is the significant marking, the vertical bar in the left is pin 1 indication.
Picture from lcsc:


+1 and just a side note for those wondering, "How do people know how to find this?" By searching on Google Images, "V7 SOT23-6", it's very likely one of the first devices that pops up. SOT23-6 is the package/shape type of this IC.

Thank you for help Sir. You save my life :)
